# Cannot change UIButton text color in a delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have a class which calls an API method and once the request is finished, it calls a delegate method on my controller view, where I do:

```
[self.myButton setEnabled:NO];
self.myButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
NSLog(@"%@", self.myButton.titleLabel.textColor);
```

To change the text color from blue to gray to let a user know he/she cannot click the button second time.

But, the color doesn't change. This is what's in the debug log:

```
UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.5 1
```

Why? When I do the same in the:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

It works and changes the color of the text on the button to gray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this in you viewDidLoad

```
[self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

When you will do the setEnabled:NO, it will automatically switch to the disable state and so the text color will be set to gray.

Comment: For you info, it works also with other buttons parameters, like the text, the background image, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should do all UI updates on the main thread. That's what's probably the problem.